# create new project using appfuse

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, appfuse

i use following command in

http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart

mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-struts-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse

it gives me error

Required goal not found: archetype:generate in org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:1.0-alpha-7

I need some help to create new project using appfuse

thanks

Answer (score 1):

use -U parameter in command line